# Pearson coefficient may not be bounded by 1

Tags: correlation

I am reading [this paper](http://www.jds-online.com/files/JDS-503.pdf). On the paragraph below Theorem 2.2, it says

> However, without
> the normality assumption, Pearson coefficient, ρ, may be problematic. Indeed,
> as shown in Frechet (1957), ρ may not be bounded by 1 in absolute value and
> the bounds differ for different distributions

I find difficulty to understand this statement. I am unable to read the Frechet's paper because it is not in English.

> Frechet, M. (1957). Les tableaux de correlations dont les marges sont donnees, Annales
> de l’Universite de Lyon, Sciences Mathematiques at Astronomie, Serie A 4, 13-31.

I thought the Crachy Schawarz inequality would guarantee that Pearson Coefficient lies in [-1,1]. Why does the Pearson Coefficient may not bounded by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of ambiguous terminology in that paper. The Pearson coefficient is still guaranteed to be in $[-1, 1]$, but what the authors mean is that the bounds could be tighter for certain distributions. The example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362399/fr%C3%A9chet-hoeffding-bounds-for-symmetric-random-variables) is that the correlation between $A = e^X$ and $B = e^Y$ is bounded within $[-1/3, 1]$, where $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$.